# Problems with CSS flexbox, overflow: scroll, and z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a windows 8 app using HTML/CSS with two flexbox layouts of articles (one on top of the other on the y-axis), that are set to `overflow-x: scroll`. However, I want an expanded view of an article to  encompass the whole screen, overlaying the other flexbox container, by using the `z-index` property of the article. However, it's not working. I don't think that this is IE10/Win 8 exclusive, I think its a problem with my CSS somewhere as its not working in the jsFiddle with webkit flexbox properties.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfyQW/4/) for an example. As you can see, the `expanded` article still lies under the other flexbox container.

Any help please? I have been looking for this for some time now and cannot find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this current approach is a dead end.
As I understand, a flex box item expands (or shrinks) given the container's size, thus, a full screen should be impossible if the container is smaller.

Comment: p.s. If I didn't understand the question, can you add images of the expected result.